# How to sort a 2D array by the first column using values of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array:

```
var array1 = [
["Jasper", "Diesel", "Grid", 2.7],
["Delta", "Solar", "Grid", 10],
["Alpha", "Wind", "Grid", 20]
]
```

I want to sort `array1` by the first column using:

```
var sortingArray = ["Alpha","Jasper","Delta]
```

So it should look like this:

```
var sortedArray = [
["Alpha", "Wind", "Grid", 20],    
["Jasper", "Diesel", "Grid", 2.7],
["Delta", "Solar", "Grid", 10]
]
```

I've already tried using the below `sort` function but it doesn't change the array at all. Do I not need to specify which position I want to sort?

```
array1.sort(function (a, b) {  
  return sortingArray.indexOf(a) - sortingArray.indexOf(b);
})
```

UPDATE: Since posting I have solved the issue. As I suspected, I did need to provide which position I wanted to sort. The solution is:

```
array1.sort(function (a, b) {  
  return sortingArray.indexOf(a[0) - sortingArray.indexOf(b[0]);
})
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are arrays. You want the first element of them -> `a[0]`/`b[0]`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: _"UPDATE: Since posting I have solved the issue..."_ - Then either add it as an actual answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are arrays, the first elements are strings. You can compare strings using `localeCompare` string method:

```js
array1.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1.sort(function (a, b) {  
   return sortingArray.indexOf(a[0) - sortingArray.indexOf(b[0]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the sorting array into a `Map` for quick look-up.

```js
const array1 = [
  ["Jasper", "Diesel", "Grid", 2.7],
  ["Delta", "Solar", "Grid", 10],
  ["Alpha", "Wind", "Grid", 20]
]

const sortingArray = ["Alpha", "Jasper", "Delta"];

/**
 * Sorts the data by a list of values.
 * @param {Object[]|Array[]} data - an array of objects or arrays
 * @param {String|Number} fieldOrIndex - a field name or index
 * @param {String[]} order - the sorting order of the values
 * @return {Object[]|Array[]} sorted data
 */
const sortWith = (data, fieldOrIndex, order) => {
  const orderMap = order.reduce((acc, token, index) =>
    acc.set(token, index), new Map);
  return data.sort((a, b) =>
    orderMap.get(a[fieldOrIndex]) - orderMap.get(b[fieldOrIndex]));
};

const sorted = sortWith(array1, 0, sortingArray);

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If your list or items is small, you can skip the map and just grab the indices.

```js
const array1 = [
  ["Jasper", "Diesel", "Grid", 2.7],
  ["Delta", "Solar", "Grid", 10],
  ["Alpha", "Wind", "Grid", 20]
]

const sortingArray = ["Alpha", "Jasper", "Delta"];

/**
 * Sorts the data by a list of values.
 * @param {Object[]|Array[]} data - an array of objects or arrays
 * @param {String|Number} fieldOrIndex - a field name or index
 * @param {String[]} order - the sorting order of the values
 * @return {Object[]|Array[]} sorted data
 */
const sortWith = (data, fieldOrIndex, order) =>
  data.sort((a, b) =>
    order.indexOf(a[fieldOrIndex]) - order.indexOf(b[fieldOrIndex]));

const sorted = sortWith(array1, 0, sortingArray);

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Also known as [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79938/what-optimizations-are-premature)...